# Enclosing a breezeway between house and garage, (there is an existing roof )

Tags: cement, stucco, board

I am in Calif. I would like to enclose my breezeway. At front of house would be solid, possibly a transom window at top. At back yard side of breezeway, a set of French doors with a vinyl window at each side. I can't find anybody to do it for me, so I think I should try it myself.

Although the front of house is lapboard, Iwould like this wall to be stuccoed. Would like to use cement board rather than plywood. Wondering how far back I should place the bottom plate to accommodate thickness of finish materials. Also, since bottom plate will be placed on existing concrete slab, I’d like to use a well recommended caulking under it so water will not creep in.

Comment: You put the bottom plate where you want it and the finish sticks out from there. If you need the finish to be at a specific place, you measure the thickness of the finish material and set the wall back that much. Follow Lee Sam's advice and don't try to line up a new wall with an existing one in a straight plane - it won't end well...

Comment: Stucco on cement board? Ok it will require a more robust frame work and not be as good of a base for stucco. The wire or mesh needs lots of support cement board is not a good idea in my opinion even though it rarely freezes  where I grew up I would use plywood or OSB with a vapor barrier. I can see this not turning out well and the stucco not lasting. Yes I have done stucco in the north Bay Area.

Comment: Don’t forget Code requires a 36” wide front door. If you enclose the existing front door, you’ll need to add another that’s not in the garage.

Answer (score 0):

Never try to align a new wall with an existing wall, unless you are using the same identical materials.

Your plan calls for different materials, so I’d recommend you step the wall back a few inches so it doesn’t look like a mistake.